# REST method for UI and API access

Tags: api, rest, authentication, flask

Folks:

This is a REST design question, not specific to any programming language. I am creating an application backend that is accessed via REST APIs. I would like to use the same APIs for both UI and API-based access. I am trying to figure out the best way to authenticate users so that I can reuse the same methods.

My current thinking on authentication is as follows:

**API Users**

These users get a user GUID and a pre-shared symmetric key. On each API request they include additional headers or request parameters that contain:

1. Their GUID
2. A security token that contains the user GUID, the current timestamp and another GUI (token GUID) concatenated together and encrypted using the shared key

Upon receiving the request, the server looks at the claimed GUID, retrieves the shared key, attempts to decrypt and verifies the token.

**UI Users**

These users will make a login request, supplying human credentials (userid/password). Once authenticated, a session is established backed by cookies and further REST calls are secured based on this session.

**The Problem**

What is the best way to write one REST endpoint that secures both ways: API access and UI access cleanly without too much duplication? I am looking to do the equivalent of the following, but perhaps more cleanly:

```
@app.route('/')
def hello():
    user = None
    if session:
        user = get_authenticated_user()
    else:
        user = process_auth_headers()
    # Do something with user
```

I am looking to code the server in Flask, but I am sure the solution will apply as easily to any REST-based server-side framework.

Looking forward to some insights from the community.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We use node for our server, but I think the method we use is pretty common. There are session libraries that express can use, and they can utilize pretty well any database to store session information. They use a cookie with a key that does a lookup on the database when the client comes in. The session data is created when the client authenticates, and the cookie with the client key is added to the browser. The clients GUID is stored in the session, it never leaves the server. We use that info when they hit the server to check if they are logged in, who they are, and what they can do. We have used both FB, (client checks FB, then sends the FB id and token down to the server, which then rechecks and sets up the session or rejects it,) or the old classic, email and password. This works well when you have to scale across multiple app servers, as session is independent of the server, it works for both mobile clients and the web.

Comment: Thanks CargoMeister. Can you give me an example of a REST method on the server that handles both sessionless API requests as well as a session-aware UI request?

Comment: Well, sessionless is a problem. We develop for mobile and web, and in mobile, there are are http request modules that operate exactly as a browser. So, is this available to you?

Comment: well, if you can't use sessions for the API, then what you've done is all you can do. Really, if you set the user up through two different functions, that's it, you should be able to avoid code duplication. Not sure what else you're looking for, I thought you were questioning the fact that you are passing the token around,